# How to keep track of clients user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I am developing an MVC application where users can login and play a game. When a user logs in, the user object is stored in a session variable. This variable is read multiple times and from basically anywhere in the application. The problem ofcourse, is that when a second user logs in, the session variable will be changed to the new user. So the "old" user can't reach his object anymore. I've been searching the internet for a good way to store the data client side. But can't find one. What is the correct way to keep an object like a session, but client sided?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: why? it's not relevant?

Comment: are you using the same browser for the second user?

Comment: @SergiuMuresan Can be the same, can be different

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try store a list of the object in your session variable, then send the "old" user ID to server side and filter the list by the user ID.

This is my suggestion, hope it helps :)

```
List<GameDetails> sessionList = Session["GameDetailsModelList"] as List<GameDetails>;
var gameDetail = sessionList.Where(x => x.userID = param).FirstOrDefault();
```